# Can't search in dictionary

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I found some code to hold my variables as dictionary type however I can't perform search. I tried different things and got different errors. My variable is:

```
Public controlList As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
```

How can I search for an item in this dictionary?

Edit: I created this variable in a module named GlobalVariables and I'm trying to call it from a class ControlAdderClass

and one of the code I tried:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To controlList.Count - 1
    Dim value As Dictionary(Of String, String) = controlList(i)
    Try
        MessageBox.Show(controlList(i), Str(value))
    Catch
        Console.WriteLine("Error")
    End Try
Next
```

and this gives me this error several times:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mirc_dialog.exe
```

Comment: What did you try? What were the errors? Also, you have a list of dictionaries, not just one. What exactly are you trying to search for?

Comment: Looks like you should have done a custom class object and made a List of that.

Comment: no, this code is in a module alone. I wanted to create global variable.

Comment: do I need it? I'm just trying to make something like multidimensional array. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The first thing you should do is to set **[option strict on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)**. When done, VS will error out the following line:

```
MessageBox.Show(controlList(i), Str(value))
```

With the following error message:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called with these arguments.

The messagebox class doesn't have an overload of the `Show` method accepting a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` like:

```
Public Shared Function Show(text As Dictionary(Of String, String), caption As String) As DialogResult
```

Without option strict on, VS choose the first overload matching the number of arguments. In your case it's [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Shared Function Show(owner As IWin32Window, text As String ) As DialogResult
```

And as observed, you cannot cast a dictionary to an IWin32Window.

---

**Solution**

> *"How can I search for an item in this dictionary?"*

Well, here's a simple example:

```
Dim keyToFind As String = "a_key"
Dim valueToFind As String = "some_value"

For Each dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String) In GlobalVariables.ControlList
    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dictionary

        Dim keyMatched As Boolean = (String.Compare(pair.Key, keyToFind, False) = 0)
        Dim valueMatched As Boolean = (String.Compare(pair.Value, valueToFind, False) = 0)

        If (keyMatched AndAlso valueMatched) Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Key={0}, Value={1}", pair.Key, pair.Value), "Found")
        ElseIf (keyMatched) Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Key={0}", pair.Key), "Found")
        ElseIf (valueMatched) Then
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Value={1}", pair.Value), "Found")
        End If

    Next
Next
```